# Why won't these two UIViews fade in and out using my animation? 

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I have two views that I would like to fade in and out.  I tried the code below, but it does not seem to work, the transition only happens once.  Can anyone tell me the right way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
vView1.alpha = 0.0;
vView2.alpha = 1.0;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
vView1.alpha = (vView1 == 0.0) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
vView2.alpha = (vView2 == 0.0) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I set this up in viewWillAppear, in case that matters.

From the Apple Doc:

```
animationRepeatCount
Specifies the number of times to repeat the animation.

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger animationRepeatCount
Discussion
The default value is 0, which specifies to repeat the animation indefinitely.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared In
UIImageView.h
```

Comment: the text from the Apple Doc, is referring to a UIImageView, which you dont seem to use. In a UIView it says about repeatCount: "If you specify the value 0, the animation is performed once without repeating."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIImageView` class also has an `animationRepeatCount` attribute, when set to 0 means "repeat indefinitely". The `UIView` class's attribute when set to 0 means "repeat once."

You're using UIView animation.

If you want to repeat this animation indefinitely, you might try setting a selector to execute when the animation finishes using `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` that simply calls your function to do the animation. Remember to also call `setAnimationDelegate:` with a value of `self` so that your selector actually gets invoked.

Comment: Ahhh yes, my mistake, I searched the doc and did not realize it was UIImageView I was looking at... duh!  I will try your suggestion, sounds good. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple documentation :

> repeatCount
>   The number of times animations repeat. This value can be a fraction. If you specify the value 0, the animation is performed once without repeating.

That's why you see your animation only once.

Comment: I edited my post because in the Apple Doc it says, "The default value is 0, which specifies to repeat the animation indefinitely."  I set it to 0, so it should repeat indefinitely, correct?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want vView1 to appear and then disappear again. Then setting repeatCount to 1 should work. And leave out the if statement, something like this:

```
vView1.alpha = 0.0;
vView2.alpha = 1.0;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
vView1.alpha = 1.0;
vView2.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Almost, I want vView1 to appear, vView2 to disappear, then vView1 to disappear and vView2 to appear, I want this to repeat forever.  So, first 1, then 2, then 1, then 2, then 1, and so on and so on... Make sense?